# Copy Multiple Ranges from userform to worksheet in another workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I am having a hard time with an issue I have with an excel workbook im trying to create that will parse multiple ranges defined in a userform from another workbook. My issue is that when i am attempting to paste the range in the form, the code will only paste the string and not the code itself.

Note: this is a mod attempt of Jan Karel Pieterse's range userform workaround

code below:

```
Private Sub cmbOK_Click() 'VALIDATION OF RANGE
Dim wbk As Workbook
Dim wst As Worksheet
Dim vbk As Variant


vbk = "[" & Me.cbxWorkbooks.Value & "]" & Me.refSelectCells.Value

If refSelectCells.Text <> "" Then
    If TypeName(Selection) = "Range" Then
        If IsValidRef(refSelectCells.Text) Then
            OK = True
            Windows("abc_123_Review_Automation.xlsm").Activate
            Worksheets("CalculationSheet").Range("A2") = vbk.Value

        End If
    End If
End If
Me.Hide
End Sub
```

Example:
  if vbk's value is "[Workbook]sheet1!a4:j365"
  I want to paste the contents of that range address into a new workbook at "A2"

Please Help!

Answer (score 0):

`Range("A2")` returns a range object.

If you want to modify the formula of the cell you should modify `Range("A2").FormulaR1C1`. 
If you want to modify the value you should modify`Range("A2").Value`.

Comment: i changed `Range("A2")` to `Range("A2").Value` it gave me a 424 error